# How to check attr class for string?

Tags: jquery-selectors

How to check attr class for string?

E.G.

HTML:

```
<p class="p_header"></p>
```

How to check that `'p'` has in it's class `'_header'`string?

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("p[class$='_header']")
```

OR

```
$("p[class*='_header']")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `......className.indexOf('_header') != -1`

Do you need more details than that?

Comment: so how can I select that element?

Comment: I can't answer that without more of your html structure. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, jQuery. `$("p[class*='_header']")` - this works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna check for a string within a p's class, you may use a simple search. 
Say you have your 'p' inside a div.

```
$('#your_div p').first().attr('class').search("_header")
```

This returns -1 if false or no match found, &
     index if true or match found.

OR you can directly access your 'p' using other answers submitted here.

Comment: `.search` looks really clean here. Thanks for submitting this option.

Comment: What jQuery function is `search()`? I've never seen that one, and I searched the jQuery docs.

Comment: I think search() function is from javascript primarily. May be thats why its not in jQuery docs.